# Process of electrical engineering

Tags: power-engineering

If I understand this right, making robots like the Nao robot or drones or making the iPhone is made by the process of electrical engineering. Is this right? I don't know if I should be using the word 'process' but I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Use the word "Zen" instead.

Comment: I searched up the meaning of Zen but I don't know how this is a good replacement. @NickAlexeev

Comment: Industrial design, materials science, electrical engineering, software engineering, manufacturing, process engineering, test engineering, ...

Comment: Making iphones and robots is the process of manufacturing. Engineering occurs during the design and prototypes stage, early processes in a products life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical engineering is one of many engineering disciplines that is involved in designing and producing those products.

I would say "[practice of electrical engineering](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practice%20of%20electrical%20engineering&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractice%20of%20electrical%20engineering%3B%2Cc0)" might be more common, but  it's not the most common phrase in idiomatic English. You might try the ESL stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

To **make** a robot, drone, or iphone all require electrical engineering skills (i.e. the practical application of knowledge to design & build things), however, it often requires the skills of other professionals (e.g.: material scientists, aerospace engineers, software programmers, mechanical engineers, etc.).

Once the design & prototype are finished, then most products require a manufacturing process to be designed, assembled/built, tested, operated & maintained in order to **make** (i.e. manufacture) a finished product/s in high volume/s.